# Find largest value x in array a so that -x also in a using C code (interview question)

Tags: c, arrays, performance, hashset

You get an array `a` of integers. Need to return the largest value `x` in `a` so that `-x` is also in `a`. If there's no such value - return 0.

Example:

For `[6,5,2,-1,-2,-5]` the return value is `5` since `-5` is in the array (the answer isn't `6` since `-6` isn't in the array).

**Edit:** the input array isn't necessarily sorted.

Now, if I could use Java - I would solve it using `HashSet` which I'll add all array elements to in their absolute value, looping over the array and updating the maximum value if it's the largest I've seen so far and if I find the absolute value of it in the Hash. This will result in `O(n)` average time.

But on the interview I needed to solve it using C code, without creating any special data structures like `HashSet`.

The only idea I had was to sort the array, use two pointers (one for the start and one for the end) and move the pointers toward each other till I find the answer.
This wasn't good enough since it's `O(nlogn)`.

Do you have an idea how can I solve it in C code in `O(n)`, using built-in libraries only?

Comment: @KamilCuk it isn't

Comment: A solution with a bad space complexity would be to find the largest element `max` in `O(n)` and create an array with `max+1` elements `arr[max+1]`. You can then use this array as hashset. I do not think of it as a good solution but you do not need to create any data structure. The restriction that you are not allowed to create data structures or use a hashset seems a bit arbitrary to me.

Comment: Also note that your approach in Java with a HashSet would not work if for example the largest element occurs twice in the array. For a number `x` you do not know if `-x` is also element of the array or just `x` a second time since you only remember the absolute value.

Comment: @Mark Is the array sorted as in your example?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow He mentioned that he had the idea of sorting the array but it was declined. Therefore I think the array is not sorted in general.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow , we can't assume the array is sorted

Comment: @Osiris, You are right - indeed my approach with the HashSet won't work in the case you wrote. However, we can do a little fix to this approach and I believe it will work.

Comment: Stray thought, sort and copy negative values to separate array, then sort on `abs` of values and take top two adjacent number that also have an entry in the negative array. Don't know how the time complexity works out there, but don't look like it would be prohibitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int found = 0;
int n = 0;
int len = 6; // your array has 6 elements
for(int i = 0; i < len -1; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < len; j++) {
        if(a[i] == -a[j] && (found = 0 || abs(a[i] > n)) n = abs(a[i]);
    }
}
if(found) printf("Number is : %d\n", n);
else printf("Not found");
```

Ok, this is the real O(n) solution without libraries, but requires an ordered array. Just one loop, and moving the pointers initial and final.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[] = {6,5,2,-1,-2,-5};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int* left = a; // point to first
    int* right = a + 5; // point to last
    while(right > left) {
        int result = *left + *right;
        if(!result) {
            printf("Number is %d\n", *left);
            return 0;
        }
        if(result > 0) left++;
        else right--;
    }
    printf("No result");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: how is this O(n)? And you should give some explanation instead of just posting code

Comment: You are right. I did not read to the end. BTW: I forgot to set found to not 0. The solution is O(n*n). If you want O(n*logn) the array must be sorted I think.

Comment: Sorry, we can't assume the array is sorted.